# dijit/form/FilteringSelect not working in phone

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

i have a drop down using dijit/form/FilteringSelect which is not supporting in mobile but it is working on web. i need my drop down to work in both web and mobile.can any one help

require(
        [ "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Memory, FilteringSelect) {

```
var filteringSelect = new FilteringSelect({
            id : "statusList",
            value : "id",
            style : "width: 150px;",
            maxLength: "50",
            placeHolder : "-- select one --",
            displayedValue : defaultStatus,
            onChange : setStatusId,
            store : dataStore,
            }, "statusList");
        filteringSelect.startup();
    });
```

Comment: Have a look at dojo mobile (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to [dojox/mobile/SearchBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/SearchBox.html) widget.

It'll do the same job than dijit/form/FilteringSelect with approximately the same configuration (You can pass to it the same datastore).